# how to get previous external link using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I'm using Laravel to build my project I need to get previous links when user access /home Route to echo it can I do this? 
I tried to use this method

```
request()->headers->get('referer')
```

but it doesn't work 
advise me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use `url()->previous()`

But it will not work it, for example, you will go straight from https://stackoverflow.com to http://localhost/ , it will just show you http://localhost

Comment: is there any way to get stackoverflow url instead?

Comment: If you don't have `referer` in your request, there is no way to get previous url